# Matrix design for d3 chords

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I would like to draw chords diagram my data is is in two json files stored.

The first one contain the length of each outside fields:

```
[
  {
    "color": "#996600", 
    "id": "chr03", 
    "len": "35020413", 
    "label": "chr03"
  }, 
  {
    "color": "#666600", 
    "id": "tig00007144", 
    "len": 40868, 
    "label": "tig00007144"
  }, 
  {
    "color": "#666600", 
    "id": "tig00026480", 
    "len": 95961, 
    "label": "tig00026480"
  }, 
...
]
```

and the relationship are stored in the following json file:

```
[
  {
    "source": {
      "start": 30824, 
      "end": 23113, 
      "id": "tig00007144"
    }, 
    "target": {
      "start": 33203431, 
      "end": 33211142, 
      "id": "chr03"
    }
  }, 
  {
    "source": {
      "start": 5564, 
      "end": 1, 
      "id": "tig00007144"
    }, 
    "target": {
      "start": 33172892, 
      "end": 33178421, 
      "id": "chr03"
    }
  }, 
  ...
  ]
```

How should I design the `matrix` for d3 to represent the relationships?

Answer (score -1):

The problem was in `circle.json`. This `"len": "35020413",` had to be replaced by   `"len": 35020413,`.